# What is the difference between operator >> and operator >>> in java?

Tags: java, bit-shift

I used to use the >> operator for right shifting. Now I've just replaced it with >>> and found the same result. So I can't figure out whether these two are fundamentally equal or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first operator sign-extends the value, shifting in a copy of the sign bit; the second one always shifts in a zero.

The reason for this is to emulate unsigned integers for the purpose of doing bit operations, partially compensating for the lack of unsigned integral types in Java.

Answer (score 11):

`>>` is arithmetic (signed) right-shift, `>>>` is logical (unsigned) right-shift, as described in the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).  Try them on a negative value, and you will see a difference.

Answer (score 3):

[This explains it really well](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html). On that same page there is also a brief [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/BitDemo.java).

But for a real brief summary:

```
<< signed left shift - shifts a bit pattern to the left
  0 0 1 1 1 => 0 1 1 1 0

>> signed right shift - shifts a bit pattern to the right
   0 0 1 1 1 => 0 0 0 1 1 

>>> unsigned right shift - shifts a zero into the leftmost position
  1 1 1 0 => 0 0 1 1

~ unary bitwise complement operator
  A | Result
  0 | 1
  1 | 0
  0 | 1
  1 | 0

& bitwise and
  A | B | Result
  0 | 0 | 0
  1 | 0 | 0
  0 | 1 | 0
  1 | 1 | 1

^ xor
  A | B | Result
  0 | 0 | 0
  1 | 0 | 1
  0 | 1 | 1
  1 | 1 | 0

| inclusive or
  A | B | Result
  0 | 0 | 0
  1 | 0 | 1
  0 | 1 | 1
  1 | 1 | 1
```